# When using pipe "|" getting “The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.”

Tags: windows, batch-file

Whenever I use a pipe symbol in a batch file or a command executed in the command prompt, I get the error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". I have verified that the environment variable `ComSpec` is correct.

One more issue I see is that whenever I run a .bat file by double clicking on it, it fails with the following error:

> Windows cannot find 'E:\Path1A\Path1B\batch1.bat'. 
>   Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO9fH.png]

I figure that both of these issues are related.

Comment: What do you get for `ftype batfile` in a command prompt?

Comment: You should include some code that contains the pipe character, as we do not know if you are using it correctly. You may just need to escape the symbol with a `^`, so in code it would be `^|`

Comment: Both of those behaviors look suspicious - like there is some type of system corruption or malware. The problem can't be an autorun issue because pipes disable the auto run feature. The COMSPEC and PATHEXT variables are both good things to verify, but I don't see how improper values can result in the errors that you posted.

Comment: Also, what do you get for `assoc .bat`?

Comment: Also, the `ftype` and `assoc` commands show the local machine settings, but the current-user settings can override this, so what do you get for `reg query HKCU\Software\Classes\.bat /ve` and  `reg query HKCU\Software\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command /ve` and `reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat\UserChoice`?

Comment: For ftype batfile , i am getting batfile="%1" %*

Comment: For assoc .bat ,  i am getting .bat=batfile